# Would like to get the geometry and titles packages in plain text, but CTAN downloading gives only unconvertible html

Tags: package-writing

How can I convert CTAN packages geometry and titlesec, which download in unconvertible
html, to ordinary text.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I’m not sure I understand your question. A simple file search for, e.g., `titlesec.sty` should work, or `kpsewhich titlesec.sty` should give you the path to the file on your system. `.sty` files download fine for me, but this depends on your browser settings. Saving them instead of opening them might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're downloading them, but the html you're getting is probably just a redirection to one of the CTAN mirrors. Try the link inside the html. For titles: [try this link](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/frankenstein/titles.sty).

Geometry is a bit different since it's on CTAN as a .dtx file you need to process to create the package. Try [this link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.dtx) for `geometry.dtx`. To create `geometry.sty` from `geometry.dtx` just run `tex` (plain TeX) on it:

```
tex geometry.dtx
```

(It'll produce some other files as well.)